# Red5 server + Red5 recorder integration for video recording/playback

Tags: video, red5, javacv

I am setting up a video recording/play back application in java, with Red5 as media server. I used HDFVR as client & its running fine. 
However, I wanted to try red5-recorder as well, but  I am not able to find any resource of using red5-recorder with Red5 server (even on recorder site). Please share if someone has any good link/resource. Thanks.

EDIT - [Javacv](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) is a good open source project to capture image / video from webcam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess their FAQ section does cover everything?

http://www.red5-recorder.com/faq.php

You simply need to modify the parameter list to point to your red5 application.

Comment: Well, looks like HDFVR have better documentation, help etc. I will go with it. Thanks.